# PHP modulus confusion

Tags: php

I have a table and needs `<tr>` to be appended every 3 `td`

```
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
$count = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    if($c % 3 == 0) echo "<tr>";
    echo "
    <td>
    $row['name'];
    </td>
    ";
    if($c % 3 == 0) echo "</tr>";
    $c++;
}
?>
```

This comes up as

```
[] []
[]
[] []
[]
```

instead of

```
[] [] []
[] [] []
```

where `[]` means the data placement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch the `</tr>` output and the `$c++` counting:

```
    $c++;
    if($c % 3 == 0) echo "</tr>";
}
```

So that the `</tr>` is in sync with the next loops `<tr>`.

Comment: I would add that you should start your count at 0 since right now, it won't put the first two <td> elements in a <tr> (and also right now the first two elements are going to be grouped together instead of being in groups of three)